# Is AWS API Gateway websockets chat example fully asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm looking at AWS API Gateway websockets support, announced relatively recently -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/

They have a sample chat server example -

https://github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app/blob/master/sendmessage/app.js

which I have running, very nice.

If you send a message, the `sendmessage` Lambda broadcasts that message to all connected users via the following -

```
// Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

const { TABLE_NAME } = process.env;

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let connectionData;

  try {
    connectionData = await ddb.scan({ TableName: TABLE_NAME, ProjectionExpression: 'connectionId' }).promise();
  } catch (e) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: e.stack };
  }

  const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
    endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
  });

  const postData = JSON.parse(event.body).data;

  const postCalls = connectionData.Items.map(async ({ connectionId }) => {
    try {
      await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: postData }).promise();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.statusCode === 410) {
        console.log(`Found stale connection, deleting ${connectionId}`);
        await ddb.delete({ TableName: TABLE_NAME, Key: { connectionId } }).promise();
      } else {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  });

  try {
    await Promise.all(postCalls);
  } catch (e) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: e.stack };
  }

  return { statusCode: 200, body: 'Data sent.' };
};
```

Now unfortunately (fortunately ??) I have a Python/Erlang background, not Javascript/nodejs. So I can see what some of this is doing, namely iterating over connections in the DynamoDB table and sending the response to each. It also *looks* as if it's working asynchronously, via use of `async` and `await` keywords, which I guess are Promises. But I can't be *sure* this is acting asynchronously, which is what worries me .. if I have a single Lambda which iterates over a large number of connections and makes synchronous calls, that's not going to work.

So - specifically with respect to this portion of code -

```
 const postCalls = connectionData.Items.map(async ({ connectionId }) => {
    try {
      await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: postData }).promise();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.statusCode === 410) {
        console.log(`Found stale connection, deleting ${connectionId}`);
        await ddb.delete({ TableName: TABLE_NAME, Key: { connectionId } }).promise();
      } else {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  });
```

can I be sure that this is posting `postData` to all connections in a fully asynchronous manner ? Do I need to be worried about a single Lambda potentially pushing messages to thousands of clients ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't called **simple**-websockets-chat-app for nothing :)

By reading the code, it does exactly what you are concerned about. Only one lambda instance will fire the message to all connections.

But it's a chat room, is it common to have thousands of users ?

> It also looks as if it's working asynchronously, via use of async and
>   await keywords, which I guess are Promises

Yes, it works in an asynchronous way, but the lambda will still execute until all messages have been sent.

---

About

```
  await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: postData }).promise();
```

It puts very little pressure on the Lambda itself, making just a remote call at a time. And being async it does not wait for the response, but continues to send more and more.

(side note - I would use `forEach` instead of `map` in this case)

A solution for a absurdly high traffic chat room would be:

- In a "DispatcherLambda", split the scan from TABLE_NAME into multiple chunks, send them to an SQS queue and subscribe a Lambda to it. This way there will be multiple containers executing that code (based on the granularity you decide)

Comment: That is a terrific answer, especially the last suggestion, which is exactly where I was heading, but hadn't got there yet. Many thanks.

Comment: Good luck with your project :)